# Using EL to include dynamic values in CSS

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using JSF2 and Richfaces 4.

I have the following .css file.

```
.cobrandURL {
    background-image: url("#{resource['testfolder/#{myBean.site1}:mrk_cobrand.jpg']}");
}
```

This is not working due to the '#{myBean.site1}' part, how can I correctly include the dynamic value of this bean?

My .xhtml file:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="testfolder/#{myBean.site1}" name="style.css" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to include it in `<style>` tag in the xhtml ?

Comment: Yes. See above for my .xhtml file Jean.

Comment: Ok. but I want to say try to put your style in your xhtml (not in css file) : `<style>.cobrandURL {    background-image: url("#resource['testfolder/#{myBean.site1}:mrk_cobrand.jpg']}");
}</style>`